# I want to store a flat array of object into a nested object form (like tree format)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to store a flat array of object into a nested object form (like tree format).
I found a solution for it but can't find how does variable "root" get all the values.
Can someone help me with this understanding.

```js
var data = [
    {id: 10, Name: "a", parentId: null},
    {id: 20, Name: "b", parentId: 10},
    {id: 30, Name: "c", parentId: 10},
    {id: 40, Name: "d", parentId: 20},
    {id: 50, Name: "e", parentId: 20},
    {id: 60, Name: "f", parentId: 30},
    {id: 70, Name: "g", parentId: 30},
    {id: 80, Name: "h", parentId: 50},
    {id: 90, Name: "i", parentId: 60},
    {id: 100, Name: "j", parentId: 70}
];


const idMapping = data.reduce((acc, rec, i) => {
  acc[rec.id] = i;
  return acc;
},{});
 //console.log("idMapping=",idMapping);

let root;
data.forEach(record => {
 
  // Handle the root element
  if (record.parentId === null || record.parentId === "") {
    root = record;
    return;
  }

  // Use our mapping to locate the parent element in our data array
  const parentEl = data[idMapping[record.parentId]];
  // Add our current record to its parent's `children` array
  parentEl.children = [...(parentEl.children || []), record];
  
});
console.log("root::",root);
```

Output is like::

```
root::
{

    id:10,
    Name:"a",
    parentId:null,
    children:(2) [
     {
        id:20,
        Name:"b",
        parentId:10,
        children:(2) [...]
        },
        {
        id:30,
        Name:"c",
        parentId:10,
        children:(2) [...]
        }
    ]

}
```

Also, a better solution will also be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The comments explain it quite well? `root` gets the root node assigned to it (because it has no parent), and all the rest is a matter of linking child nodes to their parents,... but that just mutates what happens *within* the `root` node.

Comment: this approach works only for one `parentId: null`.

Comment: The `root` should get only the record where parentId=null, how does `root` holding the all the records. @trincot

Comment: `root` will get a `children` property with `parentEl.children =`, when `parentEl` happens to be the root.

Comment: yes, that's the limitation (it works for only one `parentId: null`). I will be working on it once I understand the code better. @NinaScholz

Comment: but how does `parentEl` happens to be the `root`, since both are different variables. How does the value of  `parentEl` assigned to the `root`. @trincot

Comment: Although they are different variables, they reference existing objects. And so when two variables reference the same object, they are considered equal. Whatever you mutate via one of those variables, is as if you had done it via the other as well. Compare with how pointers work in other languages.